# Android Camera2 ImageReader Image Format YUV

Tags: android, jpeg, yuv, camera2

I've got an Android application which does motion detection and video recording.  It supports both the Camera and Camera2 APIs in order to provide backwards compatibility.  I'm using an ImageReader with the Camera2 API in order to do motion detection.  I'm currently requesting JPEG format images, which are very slow.  I understand that requesting YUV images would be faster, but is it true that the YUV format varies depending on which device is being used?  I just wanted to check before I give up on optimizing this.

Answer (score 2):

All devices will support NV21 and YV12 formats for the old camera API (since API 12), and for camera2, all devices will support YUV_420_888.

[YUV_420_888](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888) is a flexible YUV format, so it can represent multiple underlying formats (including NV21 and YV12).  So you'll need to check the pixel and row strides in the Images from the ImageReader to ensure you're reading through the 3 planes of data correctly.

If you need full frame rate, you need to work in YUV - JPEG has a lot of encoding overhead and generally won't run faster than 2-10fps, while YUV will run at 30fps at least at preview resolutions.

Comment: I got it to work by using the Y only and using the smallest image size for the device.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the luminance (Y) values only, the format for which doesn't vary between devices. For the purposes of motion detection, a black and white image is fine.  This also gets around the problem on API Level 21 where some of the U and V data is missing when using the ImageReader.